# rsyslog template regexp

Tags: rsyslog

I'm trying to split login users into his own log file.

The log text to match is this: `<user name> (<IP>): logged in`

For example: `370 (10.5.21.57): logged in`

Note that user name could be an arbitrary name, not just numbers

I'll tried this template:

```
$Template hs_file,"/var/log/hs/%msg:R,ERE,1,DFLT:([0-9A-Za-z ]+) \\([0-9.]+\\): logged in--end%"
```

regexp match fine using https://regex101.com/
But I cannot make it works nor actualy rsyslog neither https://www.rsyslog.com/regex/, all logs go to **NO MATCH** file.

This is the filter:

```
if $msg contains ' logged in' then {
  action(type="omfile"
  dynaFile="hs_file")
  stop
}
```

The issue is the regexp. What is the correct one?

Thanks!